# Open a website when user clicks on a label field on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-storm

I want my BlackBerry app to open a website when I focus on its name.

Can anybody tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
final LabelField label = new LabelField(url,LabelField.FOCUSABLE);
        label.setFocusListener(new FocusChangeListener(){
            public void focusChanged(Field field, int eventType) {
                if(eventType == FOCUS_GAINED){
                    BrowserSession bSession = Browser.getDefaultSession();
                    bSession.displayPage(label.getText());
                }

            }

        });
        add(label);
```